# PHP PDO while loop isn't returning anything

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo

I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I'm doing a query to check whether there are records in a DB table called 'newCards'.

With `$count` I check how many results it's returning: it shows me '1'. But the while loop isn't returning ANY thing. The only things I'm seeing are the `<th>`'s at the top of the table, but no table records are present, while `$count` is giving '1' as a result. Which is true, cause there is actually 1 record present in DB.

How can I fix this?

```
<?php
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `newCards` WHERE `company` = :companyID");
    $query->bindParam(":companyID", $enterprise['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $count = $query->rowCount();
    echo $count;

    if(empty($query->fetch())){
        echo "Geen gevonden";
    } else {
?>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Ontvanger</th>
                            <th>Saldo</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
<?php
        while($result = $query->fetch()){
?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
<?php
        }
?>
                    </table>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Note that `fetch()` returns FALSE not only when there are no records found, but also when the querying of the db fails, from different reasons. And you can not differentiate between the two situations. This is a bug in PDO. So, I'd recommend you to use `fetchAll()` instead. It returns an empty array when no records are found, or FALSE on failure. Both situations can be handled correspondingly. Also, don't mix data access functions within HTML. Fetch all data in arrays, in the upper php code. Work with that arrays when you're building your HTML parts.

Comment: @aendeerei its returning null on an empty resultset (if I remember correctly), not false. And it's not really a bug, I don't believe it is. It's so you can loop it, and so the loop breaks when there are no more results to fetch. It doesn't adhere to the SQL-92 SQLSTATE standard, but it does work

Comment: @Qirel Thanks for ponting me out. I rechecked my docus: it definitely returns a bool FALSE. I made - I would say a lot of - research and tests one month ago. And I noted me the results. The first phrase in them is my prior comment. The second phrase is: "_Maybe on failure an exception will be thrown_" :-) That means, that I couldn't test this at that moment. And I'm referring to it as beeing a bug, because in this context it is not the natural, desirable behavior, like in the case of fetchAll().

Comment: I definitely agree that using `fetchAll()` is a good approach - but it's seemingly not a bug that it returns false with an empty resultset. Someone reported it as a bug a good while back and got the issue closed with "*working as intended*"...

Comment: @Qirel I didn't checked any official "bug" post, as I recall, but I checked the behavior as described not only by me, but also by many internet users. No, no, it is wrong to return false when no records found AND on failure. Why? Because, no exception is thrown when using fetch(). So, how can you handle the matter, if there is no way to differentiate betw. no records and fetching failure? Just for fun, test it and give me a feedback, please, if you wish.

Comment: @Qirel At last, I would say, that "_working as intended_" doesn't cover the fact, that the final intention was wrong thought :-)

Comment: I don't disagree with you, on the contrary! :-) all I'm saying is that it *works*. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#62536

Comment: @Qirel I just read the user note you gave me. That "_returns NULL to the caller_", that you rightfully presented in your comment, has a meaning which confuses me right now. Since it comes from the man who tried to log the problem to php.net as a bug, I will take it as it is and I'll dig deeper in the next days. I'm curious about it... Bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$query->fetch()` already **fetches** a record. So next call to `fetch()` fetches **next** record or **nothing** if there're no records. In your case with **one record** second `fetch()` fetches nothing, so `while` never starts.

You can change your code to:

```
if($count){?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Ontvanger</th>
        <th>Saldo</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
<?php
    while($result = $query->fetch()){
        // show row
    }?>
</table>
} else {
    // echo that no rows found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think fetch in first if is executed so that is why second returns empty,
try to assign it to var before conditions or check wit $cont var

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to return an array indexed by column names with

```
->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

More information can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

Because `fetch()` fetches the first row, even when checking in `empty()`, it will try to fetch the next row when you use `while($result = $query->fetch()){`. You can either check the value from `$count` (like shown by u_mulder), but you should beware of the note in the manual for [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) (emphasis mine)

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. **However, this behavior is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.**

You can use a `do..while` structure and check if the fetch was successful or not instead. If you change out `if(empty($query->fetch())){` with `if (!$row = $query->fetch()) {`, you check if there was a row fetched or not (as `fetch()` returns null on an empty result). Then `$row` is ready to use, and you can use it before the first loop takes place.

```
<?php 
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `newCards` WHERE `company` = :companyID");
$query->bindParam(":companyID", $enterprise['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$count = $query->rowCount();
echo $count;

if (!$row = $query->fetch()) {
    echo "Geen gevonden";
} else {
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
           <th>Ontvanger</th>
           <th>Saldo</th>
           <th></th>
       </tr>
    <?php
    do {
        ?>
        <tr>
           <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
           <td>2</td>
           <td>3</td>
       </tr>
       <?php
    } while ($result = $query->fetch());
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

- [PHP.net on `PDOStatement::rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)
- [PHP.net on `do..while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)